# String questionText="Hello good evenin${b}${u} Amit is the best ${/u}${/b} and he loves singing";

Tags: android

How to get the underline & bold text from that string..
I need output like Hello good evening "underline&bold" and he loves singing.

Comment: @ Selvin what a funny suggestion. If the text will come like as response i need to format in that way...

Comment: Just set in your strings.xml-
  <string name="total_income"><u><b>Hello</b></u></string>

Comment: @ManishSrivastava the text is not defined in String.xml. this is dynamic text.

Comment: You can use HTML tag-
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(dynamicText)) ;

Comment: And do here what you want..Bold Underline Italic

Answer (score 2):

Use this for bold and underline

```
String tempString="yourString";
  SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
  spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
  spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, spanString.length(), 0);
```

Comment: this is dynamic text so the order will not remain same.. So how can i get the position. How i ll make BOLD and UNDERLINE.

Comment: Ohh just play around with the code i think its not that difficult..right now i dont have answer for that..

Answer (score 2):

It is simple as you like.

```
Message = "<HTML><BODY><U><B>TEST STRING</BODY></HTML>"; //or Message = "<U><B>TEST STRING</B></U>";

Textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(Message));
```

you just need to add html formatted string to textview so it will render as per html format.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 textview.setText(Html.toHtml(myString));
```

where you can use html tags to make bold and underlined in the `myString` variable.

say 
`myString="My name is <b> Naresh</b>...";`